# Using TaggableManager for m2m relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-taggit

I am trying to use TaggableManager() to add tags in my form in django application but this does not seem to work.

```
class UserBookmark(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bookmark = models.URLField()
    tag = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%i %s %s'%(self.id,self.user,self.bookmark)
```

my html template:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form name = "form2" id = "form2" method = "post" action = "{% url 'savetag' %}" class = "form-inline">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class = "form-group">
         <input name = "tag"  id = "tag" required>
         <input type="hidden" id = "field1" name="bookmark" value="">
         <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Save</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

views.py :

```
def save_tag(request):

    tagslist = request.POST.getlist("tag")
    bookmark = request.POST.get("bookmark")
    obj=UserBookmark.objects.get(bookmark = bookmark)
    user = request.user.pk
    obj.tag = tagslist
    obj.save()
```

when i hit this query

```
UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__name__in = ['java'])
```

I get empty set,
while i do have records with this tag java.

earlier my `UserBookmark` model *tag* attribute was `CharField`:

```
tag = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

but this did not work because tag had a many to many relationship as a bookmark can have many tags, so CharField did not work.

Can someone tell me what needs to be corrected here?

Comment: show your View where you are saving your form.

Comment: @Satendra yes i have added my views.py now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ***[`add()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)*** to add item in ManyToMany field

```
def save_tag(request):
   # Use get() instead of getlist() beacuse in request it is a string 'Python,Data Science' not array
   tagslist = request.POST.get("tag")
   # Use split to make it a list
   tagslist = [str(r) for r in taglist.split(',')]
   ...
   # use add to add item in ManyToMany field.
   obj.tag.add(*tagslist)
   obj.save()
```

Now your query will work fine.

Comment: i tried this but i get this error ValueError at /bookmark/tag/

Cannot add [u'Python,Data Science'] (<type 'list'>). Expected <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'> or str.

Comment: is 'tagslist' a list? if not convert it into a list `taglist = list(taglist)` then try to add as per my answer

Comment: it is a list because i am using getlist

Comment: [u'Python,Data Science'] this is my tagslist

Comment: @DhruvPandey it is not a list as you can see, fetch `tag` from request like `request.POST.getlist('tag[]')` append `[]` to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160219/discussion-between-satendra-and-dhruv-pandey).